# Fetching data from useeffect

Tags: c#, reactjs

After I added some logic to the server side, I don't get the result on the client side. I tested my server with postman and I'm getting the response via postman, but not with my react app, so I think it's a client side issue, and I don't know what I'm missing.

```
    const getData= async () => {
        const { history } = props;
        const response = await fetch('member/data');
        if (response.status === 401) {
            history.push('/unauthorized');
            setUser({ ...user, loggedIn: false })
        } else {
            const data = JSON.parse(await response.text());
            console.log(data)// prints nothing to cosole
            setLoading(false);
            setData(data.allUsers);
        }
    }

    useEffect( () => {
        getData().catch(console.error);
    }, []);
```

I don't see any errors in the console, and nothing is printed to it

Server side before change:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
  return Ok(new {_usersRepository.GetAll().ToList()});
}
```

Server side after change:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
//getting user id from token...
   return Ok(new {await context.Users.Include(x => x.Enrolled).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id==id)});
}
```

Comment: "After I added some logic to the server side" - seems like something changed on the server side perhaps? We await with baited breath a view of that server side change so we can expound on why it now fails!

Comment: Thank you for adding the before/after server code.  SUGGESTION: a) Save your SQL query to a separate variable, b) set a bkpt in `Get()`, c) Look at the value returned by `var x = context.Users.Include(x => x.Enrolled).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id==id)`.  PS: Ensure "id" is correct, too!  Q: What did Postman show you after the change?  Did the server return a meaningful value?

Comment: @paulsm4 what is bkpt?. I receive the expected result via postman

Comment: Use the Visual Studio debugger to set a "breakpoint" at the start of your "Get()" method, to single-step through the code and look at the variables (including your new variable "x") before your app sends the HTTP payload back to the client.  Q: It sounds like when your client is Postman, the server is responding with "good data"  Right?  The problem is when your client is React, correct?  Q: In the debugger, also look at the HTTP request for Postman vs. React?  Perhaps the request is bad?